# Android Retrofit HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, http-status-code-422

My Android app prints this `422 HttpException` error and it comes from Retrofit but in fact, all my requests work fine.

```
    D/retryIO: -----> HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity
    W/System.err: retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity
    W/System.err:     at retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$await$2$2.onResponse(KotlinExtensions.kt:53)
    W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:161)
    W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:519)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have a logging interceptor set up and running as well but it does not print any requests that return 422. What can be the reason for that? Any 3rd party library calls? If yes, is there a way to identify that call? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/696) help?

Comment: What is purpose this specific api?. like Multipart or something?.Could you please add the code part. that will help to identify more details.

Comment: @faizy my API is doing simple POST/GET requests for CRUD operations and all my requests return 200.

Comment: @tomerpacific I think it does not because I pass the token via interceptor and it works ok.